# usage of "which"?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

I am having following ideas.

> 1. we employ both 2D and 3D shape knowledge to the working process.
> 2. This leads in distinguishing objects-A from other objects-B efficiently.

then,

> we employ both 2D and 3D shape knowledge to the processing working
>   process, *which* leads in distinguishing objects-A from other objects-B
>   efficiently.

Is it enough only to use "which" to combine these 2 sentence?

Comment: "Efficiently" does not belong at the end of the sentence: "_which leads **to efficiently distinguishing** objects-A from other objects-B_" is normal word order. Putting the /-ly/ adverb at the end of the sentence suggests to me that your native language is Chinese.

Comment: Other issues aside, the answer to your question is Yes.   'Which' serves as an excellent join for the two sentences (and in my opinion is more natural than trying to split the single up idea (essentially 'B happens because A').

Comment: @BillFranke What's wrong with using the adverb at the end of the sentence? This is common enough usage.

Comment: @KenB: Ideally, adverbs, especially adverbs of manner, immediately precede or succeed the sentence element they modify: _He **quickly ran** down the stairs_ or _He **ran quickly** down the stairs_, not _He **ran** down the stairs **quickly**._ Separating modifiers from the elements they modify can cause confusion. In the OP's S, it causes the phonic phart that always signals poor style. Sentence-final adverbs of manner are frequently, but not always, intended to modify the entire preceding **clause**, not a verb, as in this case, 100 miles away.

Comment: In addition, the argument **This is common enough usage** applies to stupidities like _Don't gamble or you'll **loose** all your money!_ and _A snake sheds **it's** skin many times a year_. In the social and legal worlds, two wrongs don't make a right; only in the world of English usage can myriad solecisms make a standard (sic), natural (sic), acceptable (sic), and grammatically correct (sic) "idiom" (I call these "idiotisms") like "He gave it to John and I" (cf. _[CGEL](http://catdir.loc.gov/catdir/samples/cam033/2001025630.pdf)_, p. 9)

Comment: Er, well, if "efficiently" is considered a manner adjunct, then it would be fine at the end. See 2002 *CGEL*, page 578 for example [11.iv.b] *"Chris had repaired it **expertly**."* Also, see *CGEL* pages 578-9 .

Answer (score 2):

The "which" is fine, but in this case you can get a better sentence overall without it:

> We use both 2D and 3D shape knowledge in the processing working process, in order to efficiently distinguish objects-A from objects-B.

"processing working process" sounds weird too, but I don't know what you're referring to so I can't make any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

It's technically correct to combine the sentences in that way. With the correction from the comments to your original phrase:

- We employ both 2D and 3D shape knowledge to the processing working process, which leads to efficiently distinguishing objects-A from other objects-B.

However, for a cause-and-effect, you can replace "*cause*, which leads to *effect*" with simply "To *effect*, *cause*"

- To efficiently distinguish *objects-A* from *objects-B*, we employ both 2D and 3D shape knowledge to the working process.

It could, perhaps, be more clear with:

- To efficiently distinguish *objects-A* from *objects-B*, we employ knowledge of both 2D and 3D shapes to the working process.

This removes the ambiguity as to whether you mean

```
apply ( both (2D) and (3D shape knowledge) )
```

or

```
apply ( both (2D) and (3D) ) shape knowledge
```

The second meaning is what I assume is correct, but it seems easier to understand

```
apply knowledge of ( both 2D and 3D ) shapes
```