# Correct usage of "which"

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality

Am I using *which* correctly when combining the following sentences?

1. The usage of normal vector for searching plane objects is introduced.
2. The method is formed by seeking points representing a plane from left to right.

> The usage of normal vector for searching plane objects is introduced, which is formed by seeking points representing a plane from left to right.

Comment: Similar: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5885/usage-of-which

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usage of "which" in and of itself is probably fine, but it sounds weird to say a method is "formed". There are a few other awkward parts of your sentences too. You might want to rework your sentences as follows:

> We introduce the use of a normal vector to search plane objects, which consists of seeking points representing a plane from left to right.

Or even better:

> We can use a normal vector to search plane objects by seeking points representing a plane from left to right.

Comment: Thank for correcting me. But further, can I write as it follows: An object searching method is introduced using normal vector analysis, which is formed by seeking points representing a plane from left to right. Sorry for asking this again.

Comment: @aki But what is 'formed'? The sentence in this Comment says that *analysis* is formed; the first proposition in your Question says that a *method* is formed; the final sentence in your Question appears to say that *usage* is formed.

Comment: @stoneyB actually I want to say, " the method is introducd by using normat vector analysis" and in the 2nd sentence i want to say how to fromed in " this method is formed by....."

Comment: So i want to know how to use which for combining these 2 ideas

Comment: @aki: I'd shy away from using "formed". It's probably the wrong word to use in this situation.